# Get content length from gzipped NSURLResponse

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I'm using `NSURLSession`'s `dataTaskWithRequest` to perform an HTTP GET with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`. `NSURLSession` will automatically un-gzip the gzipped stream. How can I get the original response's content length (i.e. the length *before* un-gzipping)? Note that:

- `NSURLResponse`'s `expectedContentLength` is the length *after* un-gzipping it.
- `NSURLSessionTask`'s `countOfBytesReceived` property is the same value as `expectedContentLength`
- While the header `Content-Length` can be obtained from `NSHTTPURLResponse`, it's not available with HTTP 1.1's chunked transfer encoding.